# How to freeze a div to the bottom of the page like a footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am able to do this except when I am scrolling in the iPad. Then it is scrolling up and down.

My requirement is that it should not move. It should stick to the bottom of the page whether you scroll the window or not.

I am using the below CSS for the div:

```
vp_skm_mobile_div{
    left:0;
    right:0;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:35px;
    z-index:300;
    box-shadow: 9px 1px 10px 0px #242424;
    padding-top:5px; 
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: whats with the weird square bracket syntax?

Comment: Please check once again

Comment: I belive that is a typo but still you are missing a # or . before css selector

Comment: @user3188025 you need to make  it like footer?? where is now it placed

Comment: If you can try using position absolute. Apple is really bad at displaying fixed positions. But you will need to redesign your code a bit and probably use a line of JS

Answer (score 1):

Change padding top to bottom.

New code:

```
  vp_skm_mobile_div{
     left:0;
     right:0;
     position:fixed;
     bottom:35px;
     z-index:300;
     box-shadow: 9px 1px 10px 0px #242424;
     padding-bottom: 5px; 
     background-color:#ffffff;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead try this

```
 vp_skm_mobile_div{
    left:0;
    right:0;
     position:fixed;
     bottom:35px;
     z-index:300;
     box-shadow: 9px 1px 10px 0px #242424;
     padding-bottom:2px; 
     background-color:#ffffff;
    }
```